# CakePHP: ArraySource + Paginator

Tags: cakephp, pagination, cakephp-2.3

with CakePHP I want to use an array with the Paginator component. I'm using the [Datasources](https://github.com/cakephp/datasources) plugin and I have created the *Fake* model:

```
<?php

/**
 * A Fake model.
 */
class Fake extends AppModel {
    public $useDbConfig = 'arraySource';

    public $records = array(
        array('id' => 1, 'name' => 'Alfa', 'height' => 300, 'width' => 300),
        array('id' => 2, 'name' => 'Beta', 'height' => 200, 'width' => 100),
        array('id' => 3, 'name' => 'Gamma', 'height' => 450, 'width' => 200),
        array('id' => 4, 'name' => 'Omega', 'height' => 600, 'width' => 50)
    );
}
```

On the controller:

```
<?php

class ExampleController extends AppController {
    public $components = array('Paginator');
    public $uses = array('Fake');

    public function justatest() {
        $this->Paginator->settings = array(
            'order' => array('id' => 'desc'),
            'limit' => 2
        );
        $records = $this->Paginator->paginate('Fake');
        $this->set(compact('records')); 
    }
```

Now, the data is retrieved correctly by the component. The "limit" condition works correctly. What doesn't work is the "order" condition: it doesn't work or the condition that I have indicated, or sort the data according to user input.

I cannot understand if I've done something wrong or if I cannot sort the data obtained with ArraySource.

---

EDIT
The view:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('id'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('name'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('height'); ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $this->Paginator->sort('width'); ?></th>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach($records as $v): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $v['Fake']['id']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $v['Fake']['name']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $v['Fake']['height']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $v['Fake']['width']; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right from the top of my head, try this :

```
$this->Paginator->settings = array(
        'order' => array('id DESC'),
        'limit' => 2
    );
```

Not sure at all

Comment: Thanks @Justin, but unfortunately this doesn't work. But it is precisely the sort that doesn't work at all. For example, it doesn't work either clicking on the "sort" link.
Instead, the paging works properly.